# Convert a python links dataframe into a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, graph

I have a dataframe that looks like:

| From | To |
| --- | --- |
| Flare | Analytics |
| Analytics | Cluster |
| Cluster | AgglomerativeCluster |
| Cluster | CommunityStructure |
| Analytics | Graph |
| Graph | CommunityStructure |
| Graph | LinkDistance |
| Flare | Data |

...

I need it to look **exactly** like this format in the below link for the echart to be produced: https://github.com/andfanilo/streamlit-echarts-demo/blob/master/data/flare.json

Conversion to a normal dictionary doesn't work. It needs to be formatted as a hierarchical dictionary with multiple levels of parent-child relationships.

```
    {
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "analytics",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "cluster",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
              "value": 3938
            }, ...
```

This is so I can make the expandable tree graph like in: https://echarts.streamlit.app/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with pandas.
import pandas with
`import pandas as pd`

And convert dataframe to dictionary with

`dictionary = dataframe.to_dict()`

Comment: You have to read the dataframe also

Comment: That doesn't format the dictionary in the format of name and nested children. The echarts plot function only takes things with name, child to make the graph. And each child can have children in turn. It needs to match the exact style of the flare.json file.

Converting it direclty into a dictionary outputs 

{'From': {0: 'Flare', 1: 'Analytics', 2: 'Cluster', 3: 'Cluster', 4: 'Analytics', 5: 'Graph', 6: 'Graph', 7: 'Flare'}, 'To': {0: 'Analytics', 1: 'Cluster', 2: 'AgglomerativeCluster', 3: 'CommunityStructure', 4: 'Graph', 5: 'CommunityStructure', 6: 'LinkDistance', 7: 'Data'}}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Managed it. Needed to add a level column and a value

If I add a level column based on the tier (0,1,2)

df.columns=["parent_id","child_id","level"]

st.write(hs_input_output_hs_df)
def recurse(parent_id, level):
# create the base result
result = {"name": parent_id} #, "level": int(level)

```
# get all of the children of this parent, one level below this one
children = df[(df.parent_id == parent_id) & (df["level"] == level + 1)]

# if there are no such children, then return without a _children key
if children.empty:
    result["value"]=1
    return result

# otherwise, recurse on each child_id
result["children"] = [recurse(child_id, level + 1) for child_id in sorted(children.child_id.unique())]

return result
```

tree = [recurse(parent_id, 0) for parent_id in sorted(df[df["level"] == 1].parent_id.unique())]

st.write(tree[0])